# Regular Expression either numeric characters or both alpha-numeric but not only alpha characters

Tags: regex

To validate a field that must have both numbers and letters, I could use:

```
/^([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/
```

But I want to additionally accept numeric only strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got the answer from http://www.javascripter.net/faq/regularexpressionsyntax.htm

well i can do an "or" function inside regx

```
/^([0-9]|([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]*)$/;
```

Answer (score 5):

You mean you want at least one number?

You could use look-ahead assertion.

```
/^(?=.*\d)[a-z\d]*$/i
```

Comment: That's a nice clean solution if the engine supports lookarounds, thus +1 :) (don't know if there are any programming language that don't support this, but I know notepad++ doesn't and the language is not specified, so I thought I'd mention this)

Answer (score -1):

this is working for me .

```
^([a-zA-Z+]+[0-9+]+)|([0-9+]+[a-zA-Z+]+)$
```

Comment: this works for mixed strings (lines) only, but not for pure numeric ones