# Regex : Finding alpha numeirc sub-strings but not strictly alphabetic and might be fully numeric

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

**Note : This question might be almost similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967373/regular-expression-either-numeric-characters-or-both-alpha-numeric-but-not-only) question but none of those solutions worked for me.**

I have a list of strings `cust_order_no = [' ORDER 4509910882', ' 4509910882']`. I want to find all alphanumeric sub-strings in each string of this list where the sub-strings essentially must contain at least one numeric character and at most all characters are numeric type i.e. reject the sub-strings which are fully alphabetic. If a sample text was `"Order n0. AA1uu67756"`, then my desired result would be `["n0.", "AA1uu67756"]`. Without regex, I can do this:

```
poss_cust_nums = [[j for j in i.split() if j.isalnum() and not j.isalpha()] for i in cust_order_no]
```

This gives me the correct desired output :

```
[['4509910882'], ['4509910882']]
```

I want to do it for all the strings present in `cust_order_no` with regex. 
**FROM THE LINKED QUESTION**, I tried these :

```
>>> p1 = r"/^(?=.*\d)[a-z\d]*$/i"
>>> [re.findall(p1, i) for i in cust_order_no]
[[], []]
>>> p2 = r"/^([0-9]|([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]*)$/;"
>>> [re.findall(p2, i) for i in cust_order_no]
[[], []]
>>> p3 = r"^([a-zA-Z+]+[0-9+]+)|([0-9+]+[a-zA-Z+]+)$"
>>> [re.findall(p3, i) for i in cust_order_no]
[[], []]
>>> p4 = r"/^([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/"
>>> [re.findall(p4, i) for i in cust_order_no]
[[], []]
```

I tried these regex options also, but none of them worked :

```
>>> [re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z].?[0-9]+', i) for i in cust_order_no]
[['R 4509910882'], []]
>>> [re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]\.?[0-9]+', i) for i in cust_order_no]
[[], []]
>>> [re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]\.?[0-9]', i) for i in cust_order_no]
[[], []]
```

What would be right regex pattern for this type of search?

Sample input 1 :

```
[' NOI Code:50010 by 49 CFR 4509910882 PER DUPONT']
```

Sample output 1 :

```
[['50010', '49', '4509910882']]
```

sample input 2 :

```
[' (SID) number must be shown on all f bills and ', 'correspondence 7800275358']
```

sample output 2 :

```
[[], ['7800275358']]
```

Comment: Does it have to be using only regex?

Comment: Would a `re.findall(r'\d+', x)` do the trick for you? If it's just that you want to find all "connected" numbers, then this will give it to you.

Comment: @HampusLarsson It won't work for cases like `"Order n0. AA1uu67756"`. It would produce `['0', '1', '67756']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do what you want. It looks for a word break, then uses a positive lookahead to check for 0 or more alphabetic characters followed by a digit, then captures characters up to the next word break:

```
\b(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d)[A-Za-z0-9]+\b
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vqMuD7/1)

In python

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('\\b(?=[a-zA-Z]*\\d)[A-Za-z0-9]+\\b')
str = [' NOI Code:50010 by 49 CFR 4509910882 PER DUPONT']
print ([pattern.findall(i) for i in str])
str = [' (SID) number must be shown on all f bills and ', 'correspondence 7800275358']
print ([pattern.findall(i) for i in str])
str = [' ORDER 4509910882', ' 4509910882']
print ([pattern.findall(i) for i in str])
str = 'Order n0. AA1uu67756'
print (pattern.findall(str))
```

Output

```
[['50010', '49', '4509910882']]
[[], ['7800275358']]
[['4509910882'], ['4509910882']]
['n0', 'AA1uu67756']
```